# Retrieving list of Sql Server instances on the local PC and the network

Tags: sql-server

How can one determine which sql server instances are installed on the local machine and the network environment?

Comment: http://www.straightpathsql.com/blog/2009/2/25/what-sql-instances-are-installed-on-my-network.html

Comment: I want to both upvote and downvote this simultaneously. It sounds like a great tool for solving this problem, but this is a programming site, not a sysadmin site.

Comment: @Kenny I'm not sure what your comment has to do with the answer. Maybe you should suggest that the *question* be migrated to ServerFault or dba.stackexchange.

Comment: your answer links to a page that describes a program that provides the info the OP is seeking, but I found this question because I wanted to know how to generate a list of SQL Server instances in code. Your answer is basically "Use the Microsoft Assessment and Planning Toolkit to generate an Excel spreadsheet of SQL Server instances." One _could_ (probably) integrate that program into their own code, but this seems to miss the point of this site – 'how do I do _X_ (in code)'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the EnumAvailableSqlServers method in the SMO (SQL Management Object) library.  Check out [Sample 1](http://devpinoy.org/blogs/keithrull/archive/2006/06/08/Programmatically-List-All-SQL-Servers-And-Their-Databases-Using-SMO-.aspx) or [Sample 2](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=45)

Answer (score 1):

`sqlcmd` and `osql` have the option `-L` which list the instances. [Here](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1113) and [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/18/sql-server-find-all-servers-from-local-network-using-sqlcmd/) are examples and tutorials how to use it.